# Placeholder in the QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

It is possible to set a placeholder for cell?
I think it can implement by set QLineEdit for particular cell, but may be QTableWidget, or QTableWidgetItem can do this without custom widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QTableWidget::setCellWidget()` to set any widget for the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know this path. If no other solution will be proposed I'll mark this answer as correct.